# What will happen after bundling 2 .js files which have a function with same name and Parameter using bundle.config?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, bundle

If two `.js` files having functions with the same name and parameter but the code is different. What will happen after bundling using `bundle.config`?

Which one will call?

Or/And how can we fix that?

```
//in parent.js file  
function getdetails(id)  
{  
    //enter code here  
}

//in student.js file  
function getdetails(id)  
{  
    //enter code here  
}
```

Comment: I believe that the function that is coming last will be chosen.

Comment: Are they both exported to the global scope? If so, then you'd get the second `getdetails` as it overrides the first. And you'd get the same problem regardless of bundling. Although if they are only used locally, they'd *likely* be bundled within an IIFE to separate them from other scopes. That will depend on your bundling configuration, I believe.

Comment: As it stands, only the second version will be run. Technically the variable `getdetails` gets redefined with the last one that gets parsed. The number or arguments makes no difference and cannot be used for function overloading, it just doesn't work in JavaScript

Comment: Any idea how to handle that conflict/overload. Because student side getDetails of student.js should execute and parent side getDetails of parent.js. after bundling all files will combine, then how i can identify which function belongs to which role/js.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of bundler, normally functions are scoped from the modules they are exported from.

So for example:

```
//in parent.js file  
function getdetails(id)  
{  
    //enter code here  
}

//in student.js file  
function getdetails(id)  
{  
    //enter code here  
}
```

In the bundled javascript, they become (as an general example):

```
_parent.getdetails()
_student.getdetails()
```

You could check your un-minified bundled code and search for `getdetails` to see how the functions are being scoped for clarification.

*Side note*

If two functions are being defined with the same name, in the same scope (which shouldn't be the case here), then the function re-defined each time.

```
//in parent.js file  
function getdetails() {console.log("foo");}

function getdetails() {console.log("bar");}

getdetails(); // Outputs "bar"
```